# Can't call setState in unmounted component while working on login part

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a login functionality with Facebook and I see this issue  in my console. It says:

```
Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. 
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.     
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
```

I get the console log of `userProfile` where we see the response from Facebook and after that the execution of the code stops. I don't see my login getting dispatched because of this, the `setState` should happen.

Here is the login code and we are doing `setState` only at one part.

```
class SocialLogin extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        userData:""
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        console.log("d",d);
        console.log("s",s);
        console.log("id",id);
        debugger
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        console.log("js",js);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    window.fbAsyncInit = ()=> {
        window.FB.init({
            appId: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,//Change with your Facebook app id
            autoLogAppEvents: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v3.0'
        });

        window.FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', response => {
             console.log("event",response);
             debugger
            if (response.authResponse) {
                this.checkLoginState();
            } else {
                console.log('[FacebookLoginButton] User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        });
    };
}
// componentDidUpdate(){
//     console.log("updateduserprofile",userProfile);
//     this.props.loginUser(userProfile);
//     debugger
//    //window.location.href="https://rooter-web-app-dev.firebaseapp.com/home/cricket"
// }

checkLoginState(){
    debugger
    window.FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        console.log("response inside checklogin",response);
        this.statusChangeCallback(response);
    }.bind(this));
}

login(){
    window.FB.login(this.checkLoginState(), {scope: 'email'});
}

statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log("response",response);
    accessToken =response && response.authResponse && response.authResponse.accessToken;

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        this.testAPI();

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        console.log("[FacebookLoginButton] Person is logged into Facebook but not your app");
    } else {
        console.log("[FacebookLoginButton] Person is not logged into Facebook");
    }
}

testAPI() {

    window.FB.api('/me' ,(response)=> {
        console.log("testAPI",response);

       if(response){
           userProfile = {
                  auth:accessToken,
                  id:response.id,
                  name:response.name,
                  provider: "Facebook",

                };
                console.log("userProfile",userProfile);
                this.setData(userProfile);
       }

        console.log('[FacebookLoginButton] Successful login for: ', response);
    });

}
setData=(userProfile)=>{
    this.setState({
        userData:userProfile
    },()=>{
        console.log('inside setData');
        if(userProfile!==undefined){
            console.log("inside callback",userProfile);
            this.props.loginUser(this.state.userData);
        }

    });
}

render(){
    return (
        <div style={loginstyle}>
        <button onClick={()=>this.login() }  className="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook">
          Login with Facebook
         </button>

       </div>
    )
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     z
```

Answer (score 1):

before updating the state of the component you need to check does it mounted?? if not mounted then do not update to state of it,to do it you will need to maintain flag indicating the mount status of component 
consiger the following code

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state={
      userData:""
   };
  //initially its false
   this.mount=false
 }
componentWillUnMount(){
    //make it false here
    this.mount=false;
}
componentDidMount() {
//make it true when mounted
    this.mount=true;
}
```

now before making use of setState make sure this.mount is true ,hope it will help!

Answer (score 1):

you need unsubscribe when component will unmount.

```
onAuthStatusChange = response => {
  console.log("event",response);
  if (response.authResponse) {
    this.checkLoginState();
  } else {
    console.log('[FacebookLoginButton] User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
  }
}
```

...

```
window.FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', this.onAuthStatusChange)
```

and when componentWillUnmmount

```
componentWillUnmmount() {
  window.FB.Event.unsubscribe('auth.statusChange', this.onAuthStatusChange)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to set your state after your component has been unmounted (ex: navigating to another page). So to prevent it for happening try this one:

```
    _isMounted = false;

    componentDidMount(){
        this._isMounted = true;
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        this._isMounted = false;
    }
```

And in that `testAPI` add this:

```
if(this._isMounted)
{
    this.setData(userProfile);
}
```

And it will update the state only if the component is mounted